# Cannot locate my Hydration Error: Initial UI does not match what was rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am getting a Next Hydration Error (https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) and have been trying to locate the JSX element that is giving me this error for about two hours. Can anyone see what is wrong?

**ApiLayout.tsx**

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import ApiNavbar from './ApiNavbar';
import Header from './Header';
import Image from 'next/image';

const ApiLayout = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <main className="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
        <ApiNavbar />
        <section className="m-5 flex-1">
            <div className="p-2.5 md:mt-[-5rem] md:p-5 md:max-w-5xl md:mx-auto">
              <article className="block pt-5 md:relative md:px-20 md:pt-9 md:pb-[6.25rem] text-[1.125rem] bg-white break-words p-pages heading-7 heading-8">
                {children}
              </article>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ApiLayout;
```

**ExplorePage.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ApiLayout from '~/common/layout/P-Layout/ApiLayout';
import Heading from '~/common/layout/P-Layout/customs/Heading';

const ExplorePage = () => (
  <ApiLayout>
    <Heading>Explore API</Heading>
    <section>
      <iframe id="explorer" src="my source" width="700" height="1000" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
        iframe = document.getElementById("explorer"); iframe.src = iframe.src + window.location.hash;
      </script>
    </section>
  </ApiLayout>
);

export default ExplorePage;
```

Comment: This is most likely because of that `script`. Also, in Next.js, it's recommended to use the built-in [Script component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script).

Comment: @ivanatias This was great and solved it, I forgot next has a built-in Script component. Thank you!